# Does anyone have experience with performing symbolic regression using Mathematica?

Tags: packages, fitting, symbolic, commercial-package

I understand that there is at least one Mathematica package, DataModeler commercially available for symbolic regression. I'm seeking any observations with this or any other similar tool.

I'm interested in solving single input/single output as well as multi input/single output problems.

Comment: Last time I searched for this I haven't found any freely available and useable package, but I haven't done an extensive search.  I don't think you'll find anything ready to use, but it'd be interesting to see some answers implementing very basic approaches.

Comment: For those not familiar with it, *symbolic regression* is a fitting method where the system will figure out the best simple formula to fit the data points (as opposed to having to provide a formula with unknown parameters).  [Here's an example of how these techniques might be applied.](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/sites/default/files/Science09_Schmidt.pdf)  Steve, for better answers you might want to explain this a bit in the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Sorry for not being more explicit. And thanks for the paper. This also may go by the name of "Genetic Programming".

Comment: Just an observation. Mathematica is very strong in traditional numerical regression (see NonLinearModelFit for example). Likewise I don't think there is another tool on the planet that is as strong symbolically. One would think that a logical development path for Mathematica would be the fusing of the two in a future major release, at least in a bare-bones implementation. In my opinion, SR is much more useful than say, Neural Networks.

Comment: you can check the thesis of Hussein Suleman Genetic Programming in Mathematica. The codes are available for symbolic regression, too. See, http://www.husseinsspace.com/research/publications/gpinmath.pdf

Comment: @s.s.o, thanks for sharing Hussein's thesis, nice piece of work that enlightened me on the theory. I'm not a Mathematica power user by any means, so to personally implement and maintain his work would be a large time investment and so am looking for a ready-out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Suleman's thesis is also [here](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~wbl/biblio/cache/http___www.husseinsspace.com_publications_gpinmath.pdf).

Comment: @Szabolcs Does symbolic regression as discussed here differ from [FindFormula](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html), introduced in v10.2 in 2015?

Comment: @ChrisK I think it's essentially the same, except that FindFormula is a black box with little control on how it searches for formulas

Comment: @Szabolcs [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) is a "black box", but it does have control options like the `SpecificityGoal` and `TargetFunctions`. (Control-wise those are more directly controlling than the rest.)

Comment: I am using the HeuristicLab (open source) to perform symbolic regression.

Comment: Looks interesting, but is it relevant to Wolfram Mathematica?

Answer (score 18):

I could be perceived as biased since I'm the CTO of *Evolved Analytics* ([www.evolved-analytics.com](http://www.evolved-analytics.com)) and wrote much of the *DataModeler* code over the past 13 years, however, *DM* is probably the most efficient, complete and powerful symbolic regression platform out there for any environment. In addition to the basic model development, it supports the entire workflow from data exploration to model analysis and insight generation.

The industrial and corporate analysis roots of *DM* run pretty deep and the continual enhancement draws upon our ongoing project efforts. It is not "freely available"; however, the academic and commercial licensing rates are very reasonable. We also offer two-month trial licenses (but you have to provide your own copy of *Mathematica*) for those interested in putting it through its paces.

There is quite a bit of information available at the website as well as papers and tutorials on industrial data modeling which we have presented at the major evolutionary computing conferences for those seeking more information.

Comment: Hey Mark, welcome to the party!

Comment: Are you aware of any freely available Mathematica packages, or just code examples, that demonstrate what is possible with these methods?  (I'm not looking for a fully usable or useful package, just something to give a taste.)

Comment: @Mark Kotanchek, I've seen the material at your website, very thorough and impressive. How is forward-compatibility handled? I understand that Mathematica version 10 is in the pipeline.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Bob Nachbar did a GP evolution of chemical structure about 20 years ago in a Mathematica Journal if you can dig up a copy. It was pretty good. Also, Christian Jacob had an excellent book, "Illustrating Evolutionary Computation with Mathematica" which is interesting. The other option, of course, is to explore the papers, case studies, FAQ, etc. available at the E-A site.

Comment: @Steve, DataModeler is compatible with both Mma 8 and 9. So far, we haven't found any issues with the prerelease version of Mma 10 (which I will be using for my talk at the upcoming Wolfram Tech Conference). Wolfram snuck in some significant changes in between the last prerelease and released versions of 9 which caused hate and discontent; however, we worked around those pretty quickly and we will do that as required for Mma 10. The Mma core doesn't change that much at this point so the adaptation generally doesn't take much time.

Comment: @YvesKlett, Thank you ... even though more distractions are not what I ever need. See you at WTC in a couple of weeks. If the schedule gods permit, I will be bringing our new CEO for some immersion in the Wolfram realm.

Comment: Really sorry to say but I will not be able to attend ... said gods (and their brethren at accounting) were not in favor. You will have to procure your extra dinner spirits in another fashion, too...

Comment: @Mark Kotanchek, Yikes! Hate and discontent ? Hopefully things now are as harmonious as they once were. Also, good luck with your presentation at the WTC. Will your slide package be made available shortly thereafter?

Comment: @Steve, WRI changed the help system with Mma 9 and lost some functionality in the process (the net effect is that Needs should be used to load packages rather than Get - even though Get was legal for 15 years). Otherwise, everything is harmonious. The slide packages will be available post-WTC on the E-A site as well as, presumably, Wolfram's.

Answer (score 3):

I have come very late to this party, but maybe you would like to check out Paul Knysh's "sym" package on [GitHub](https://github.com/paulknysh/sym). I played a bit with it today using Mma 11.0. The code definitely runs; however, I did not run extensive searches because I was afraid of melting my MacMini :-).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing! Yes, the code works, and it is very slow. (Over a trivial dataset.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Glad that it worked in your hands. Would you give me a +1 for it? ;-)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, Mathematica is rather limited at symbolic regression. It is preferable to use an external tool for that.

Eureqa used to be popular before it was purchased by a consulting company in 2017. In 2020 a new symbolic regression tool called [TuringBot](https://turingbotsoftware.com/) was developed, and it was shown in [arXiv:2010.11328](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11328) to be more efficient than Eureqa at finding formulas. So I would recommend TuringBot.